# Stackie - A Stack Exchange client for the Universal Windows Platform

Tags: app, windows, windows-uwp

## About

Browse your favorite questions and answers on the myriad of topics across the entire Stack Exchange network with [Stackie - a Stack Exchange client for the Universal Windows Platform](https://ravindul.github.io/Stackie).

- A beautifully crafted User Interface that is harmonious with the design language of the Universal Windows Platform.
- Syntax highlighted code and perfectly formatted math for websites such as Stack Overflow and Math Overflow.

## Screenshots

[image: Desktop Site Overview]

[image: Mobile Site Overview]

## Downloads (and more screenshots)

is available for download on the Universal Windows Platform, on desktop, laptop, tablet, surface hub, and mobile devices, via the Windows Store;

[image: Get it from Microsoft]

### System Requirements

1. Windows 10, Build 10240 or higher.
2. A minimum of 750 MB of internal memory `*`.

`*` : Stackie utilizes a `WebView` component of the Universal Windows Platform which consumes an unnecessarily large amount of system memory, for which there currently is no workaround without compromising functionality.

## Contact

All e-mails related to Stackie should be sent to stackie-concierge@outlook.com . If your e-mail fits the purpose / category listed below, use the corresponding subject to ensure it gets handled appropriately.

- Support: `[Stackie - Support]`
- Bugs/Errors: `[Stackie - Exception Report]`

## License & Code

Stackie is currently closed source, however this could (and most probably will) change in the future.

Comment: Cool. I love it.

Comment: Great to see a UWP client! Sadly a lot of mobile devices are left out at this time due to the memory requirement. Where does the dependency on `WebView` come from?

Comment: Also, I'd love to help out. I've thought of making an app myself a few times, but thought it'd be too big of a project for me since I have almost no UWP experience currently.

Comment: @Stijn the memory requirement is now 750 MB 

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'll try it out tonight :) Just noticed that my device does have 1GB of memory, not sure why the Store said I didn't have enough memory...

Comment: as a linux user myself, why are the whites so white and darks so dark. Is it microsoft theme or smth?

Answer (score 3):

Post viewing seems to be broken. The question is cut off and there's infinite scrolling, without being able to see the rest of the question or the answers. Also note that the post score says `--3` while it should say `-3`.

- Device: NOKIA Lumia 735
- Resolution: 720x1280
- OS build: 10.0.15014.1000 (Fast Ring)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

### [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) sort the sites list alphabetically

Nobody's going to remember the order the sites were created in, which is the default ordering - I suggest ordering the sites list (for pinning sites) alphabetically instead. You can use a large pagesize (999) to get every site at once - the page size is not limited on the /sites route.

### [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) make links work

Links within posts aren't clickable. That should be changed.

### [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) work on adding the other features

such as close and delete votes, editing, flagging, etc. Doing all of them will take a long time, but if you start working now you'll get there sooner.

### [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) recognize moderators

I logged into the app with my moderator account, and it didn't appear to recognize the fact that I'm a moderator in any way. That'll be important for binding votes.

---

Yep, that's a lot of feature requests, but overall I like the app. It's got promise.

Comment: By recognition of moderators, do you mean visual glyphs that indicate that a user is a moderator, or additional functionality (in which case, would you care to be a bit more specific)?

Comment: @RavinduLiyanapathirana Moderators have diamonds on Stack Exchange sites; they don't in your app.

Comment: Visual glyphs it is, then :)